# aws cdk to fetch the streamarn from the existing dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am working on the AWS CDK and New to this AWS CDK.
I have created a dynamodb table and enabled the stream.
I have another CDK job where I am trying to add this stream to the Lambda , but unable to fetch the table streamarn.

**Could you please let me know how can I fetch the existing dynamodb table streamarn.**

Answer (score -4):

I believe you can get the tableStreamArn from the new table (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html) you are creating.